# Suffix ".home" is being added to computer names on a small Windows network

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

I have a small network of Windows 10 computers. All computers show listed on the network, but one of them (**foo**) is inaccessible. Whenever I try to ping it from any other computer, a ".home" particle gets added to it, and a wrong IP address is searched. This is what I get pinging it from **bar**:

```
> ping foo /4
Pinging foo.home [192.168.25.149] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.25.1: Destination host unreachable.
```

Notice the different IP showing in the reply. If I try to ping **foo** from **foo**, I get the correct thing:

```
> ping foo /4
Pinging FOO [192.168.25.163] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.25.163: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

If I try to ping **bar** from **foo**, it's allright:

```
> ping bar /4
Pinging bar [192.168.25.112] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.25.112: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

Any idea about what's going on?

EDIT:

The network in question is operating through simple **file sharing**, not homegroups.

Comment: Nothing, and I mean nothing chnaged with Homegroup, in Windows 8+

Comment: @Ramhound at least the way users and passwords work has changed, with Microsoft accounts making simple file sharing a hell to work with.

Comment: No; You are 100%incorrect.  The fact an account is linked to a Microsoft Account does not change how a Homegroup works.

Comment: Homegroups are not being used.
And regardless, it was easy and relatively problem free to set up a file sharing windows network with Windows 7.
Windows 8 made it into a hell again.

Comment: Your brought it up.  I only correct what I saw was a factually incorrect statement.  Post the contents of your hosts file.  You should also provide the output of `ipconfig /all` for both machines.

Comment: So, there are updates to be made on this. The problem is somewhat solved.

Comment: Update: The problem is _somewhat_ solved, but not quite, so I won't post it as an answer. I did as @Ramhound suggested and looked at the ipconfigs and hosts on both and there were nothing special save a difference: **fixed DNS** on the ok machine. I just set it to fixed 8.8.8.8 on **bar** and _voilá_, foo was found properly.
It seems the DNS provided by the modem is broken, not Windows sharing. The thing is provided by the ISP and seemingly has no setting related to DNS. That worries me by a # of reasons, but also shifts the problem to somewhere else and pretty much settles the question here.